# Limit of $\frac {1}{x^2(x+7)}$ as x approaches $-7^-$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$\displaystyle \lim_{ x \rightarrow -7^{-}} \; \frac{1}{x^{2}(x+7)}$

My manual computation yields a different answer to [that of Wolfram's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%201%2F%28x%5E2%28x%2B7%29%29%20as%20x%20approaches%20-7%5E-).

And I don't understand, why isn't the correct answer: the function approaches $0$? Because that's what it does!

If denominator is expanded, then that's how the whole rational equation looks like:

$\frac {1}{x^3 + 7x^2}$

Now, since $x$ approaches $-7$ from the left, let's take a very small values that is close to $-7$ from the left. Let it be $-7.000000000001$.

$\frac {1}{-7.000000000001^3 + 7 \cdot -7.000000000001^2} = \frac {1}{-686.000000000245000000000028000000000001}$

$1$ divided by a big number? A very SMALL number, meaning the function is approaching $0$!
No? Or the function approaches a very small number, whatevs.

Why does WolframAlpha says that the function approaches infinity?

The only possible answer is that I'm not *supposed* to expand denominator, but rather keep it as factor-y as possible. Then yeah, I guess, in denominator, $x^2$ yields a big number multiplied by a very small number $(x+7)$, then $1$ divided by a very small number does indeed "shoots off" to infinity.

Comment: Wrong calculator calculation.

Comment: Excuse me? But if you divide 1/-686 you get a very small value. Go ahead, try it.

Comment: Sure, but the denominator is far from $-686$. By the way, try something like $-7.0001$. I would have to, my cheap calculator can't handle your number. And do not "simplify" first, use $x^2(x+7)$.

Comment: I think you made a mistake punching it in the calculator.  Notice that $686=2\times7^3$.  I think you messed up a sign somewhere.

Comment: @Mike yeah, in second parenthesis in denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses in your calculation. It should be: $$\frac 1{\color{green}{(}-7.000000000001\color{green}{)}^3+7\cdot\color{red}{(}-7.000000000001\color{red})^2}$$
Notice that I put one pair of parentheses in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ for your cubic power and the other pair of parentheses in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ for your square power.

Cubing a negative number does not remove the negative sign inside the parentheses, but squaring does. In general, raising a negative number to an *odd* power remove the negative sign inside the parentheses, but raising a negative number to an *even* power does.

Comment: If you have a scientific calculator or a graphing calculator, try to type this in: $$\frac 1{-7.000000000001^3+7\cdot(-7.000000000001)^2}$$ Then type this: $$\frac 1{-7.000000000001^3+7\cdot-7.000000000001^2}$$ A scientific calculator or a graphing calculator will follow the order of operations, and you will see the difference between the two numerical values reported by your calculator.